# Which JFXtras Grid to use XGrid or Grid?

Tags: java, javafx

I've seen in JFXtras 0.5 a Grid layout, org.jfxtras.scene.layout.Grid. But when I try to get examples on the web, there's only XGrid. What's the difference? Is one out-dated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XGrid is apparently part of the JFXtras version 0.6 preview.

http://code.google.com/p/jfxtras/source/browse/jfxtras.core/tags/release-0.6-preview/common/src/org/jfxtras/scene/layout/XGrid.fx

The next iteration of JFXtras will prepend most if not all classes with an X, showing in the name that these are Extensions to JFX.